# Reactjs set state in props array

Tags: reactjs

I'm New to React.js, trying to build form validation.

There is Btn component.

```
const MyBtn = ({opts}) => {

   if(!opts) {
      opts = {};
   }

   return (
      <button {...opts}}>{opts.value}</button>
   )
}
```

There is Home.js which is a login page. I don't add other codes that you might not need for this problem.

```
class Home extends Component {
    state = {
       formValid: false
    }

   regexCheck = {
       disabled : {this.state.formValid},
       value: "LogIn",
       type: "submit"
   }

   render(){
      return(
        <MyBtn opts={this.regexCheck}/>
      )
    }
}

//output that I'm trying to get
<button type="submit" disabled={this.state.formValid}>LogIn</button>
```

I get an error that I can't call {this.state.formValid} in the props. since this is a reserved word. (Sorry for my bad English.) I feel like I'm totally wrong.

Anyway, I thought I can use getDerivedStateFromProps method for this...? so I added this in Home.js but didnt work.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.formValid !== nextProps.formValid){
        return { formValid: nextProps.formValid };
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, I'm still confused by props and state. ahhhh but I still gotta keep doing this project. Please give me any idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
disabled : {this.state.formValid},
```

You simply want:

```
disabled : this.state.formValid,
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!